# Unable to setState inside a fetch function in react native

Tags: react-native

The `this.setState` inside `fetch` success is not working.

Below is the code:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response = > response.json())
    .then(json = >
    {
        var data = json.data;
        alert(data);
        this.setState(
        {
            userData: data,
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(userData)
        })
    })
    .catch (() = >
    {
        alert('ERROR GETTING DATA FROM FACEBOOK');
    })
```

Comment: _not working_ is not enough of an explanation. Please give some context to your question. Please take a look at  [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: your problem it might be that this. on the this.setState doesnt reffer to the correct scope inside the then(). It is a common issue

Comment: I tried var that = this; and then refered to setState using "that" instead outside the fetch function but didn't work